# Scaling bitmap using scale gestures without aspect ratio(horizontally or vertically)

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to scale bitmap over canvas horizontally or vertically using scale gesture. I have tried samples but they maintaining aspect ratio. but i only want to **scale vertically or scale horizontally.**

Answer (score 0):

> I have somehow resolved my problem. Here is what iam doing. If anybody is having a better solution please tell me.
>   Thanks

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float xScale = detector.getCurrentSpanX() / detector.getPreviousSpanX();
        float yScale = detector.getCurrentSpanY() / detector.getPreviousSpanY();

        float diffSpanX = detector.getCurrentSpan() - detector.getPreviousSpanX();
        float diffSpanY = detector.getCurrentSpan() - detector.getPreviousSpanY();
        /**
         * Ignore scaleX
         */
        if (diffSpanX > diffSpanY) {
            scaleFactorY *= yScale;
            scaleFactorY = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactorY, 5.0f));
        } else {
            scaleFactorX *= xScale;
            scaleFactorX = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactorX, 5.0f));
        }
        update(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        return true;
    }
}
```